# How can i remove before and after a particular xml tags in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge xml file which has many xml file is in each line.(so there are thousands of xml lines)
I want to remove all the tags before and after  tag from every line regardless of tag position in line.

```
**Input XML:**

<Main><FirstName>xyz123</FirstName><employer>ABC Co.</employer><Salary>1000</Salary><Description>Manager</Description></Main>
<Main><FirstName>xyz123</FirstName><employer>ABC Co.</employer><Salary>1000</Salary></Main>
<Main><FirstName>xyz123</FirstName><Salary>1000</Salary><Description>Manager</Description></Main>
<Main><FirstName>xyz123</FirstName><employer>ABC Co.</employer><Salary>1000</Salary><Description>Manager</Description></Main>

**Output would be something like this:**
<employer>ABC Co.</employer>
<employer>ABC Co.</employer>
<employer>ABC Co.</employer>
<employer>ABC Co.</employer>
```

Comment: Why the line restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but I guess you want:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(<employer>.*?</employer>).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  .*            : 0 or more any character
  (             : start group 1
    <employer>  : literally
    .*?         : 0 or more any character, non greedy
    </employer> : literally
  )             : end group 1
  .*            : 0 or more any character
$               : end of line
```

Comment: it Works! Thank you very much